# Which lens should I buy?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, canon-550d

I have Canon 550D and 18-55mm IS II kit lens. I shoot landscape, macro and wildlife photography. My budget is $200 and looking for some zoom lens options.

I have searched a lot and found following two lenses in my budget.

- Canon EF-S 55-250mm f/4-5.6 IS II Lens
- Sigma 70-300mm F/4-5.6 APO DG Macro (for Canon AF Digital SLR) Lens

I was reading review for **Canon 55-250mm** [here](http://www.dpreview.com/products/canon/lenses/canon_55-250_4-5p6_is_ii/amazon-customer-reviews-list?group=534007&page=1&sort=mostVotedFirst) and Mr. Vijay Venkataraman  was talking about the **58mm Canon 250D close up filter**. What do you guys think about this combination and if you guys have any other options, please suggest.

Comment: See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ Also, the question about the close up filter is really a completely different question. If you want a macro lens then ask a question about that, if you don't understand close up filters ask that, if you want a telephoto zoom lens for landscape, then stick to that, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest difference I see is that the Canon has image stabilization, and the Sigma has a bit better macro capabilities(but the Canon isn't far off and neither is true 1:1). The Canon is lighter by about 5oz.

They aren't that different of lenses in the long run. $200 is a very small budget for a high quality telephoto zoom.

Lots more comparisons and information all over the internet: http://goo.gl/gBHaj